# Why was this question tagged as off-topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

[What is the first Kanji in this image?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/80805/what-is-the-first-kanji-in-this-image/80806#80806)

> Questions asking for translations, transcriptions or proofreading are off-topic unless prior research effort is clearly indicated; we're here to help you learn, not to provide a bulk translation service nor to proofread your translations or transcriptions. See: We don't do translations.

How is the above question related to direct translation without prior research?

My question was specifically, what Kanji was present in the image because I couldn't figure it out. I did provide details of prior research as well. I fail to understand how recognizing a single Kanji from an image comes under direct/bulk translation and if it does, where exactly should I ask such questions (because being able to recognize handwritten Japanese is clearly related to language study for me) and what would qualify as prior research because I think I did provide everything that could be provided to make it a legitimate question but my question was marked *off-topic* nonetheless.

Comment: For the sake of reaching future users (i.e. others who also found the source material and could not figure it out), it could be helpful if you included more details in the OP (what is the source? the surrounding context? the surrounding dialogue?). These might help others find it. Otherwise, the OP can seem too localized despite having research. I can see how this OP and others like it could be considered off-topic, maybe not as "bulk translation without research", but as too localized in that case.

Answer (score 3):

I voted to close the question because, you said you'd searched for surnames with 口 on [a website](http://kakijun.com/kanji/name/53e3.html) and that nothing seemed to match, but I could see 森口 on the list. Also I thought you could probably have tried some other websites, not just one, for example [here 「口で終わる名前ランキング」](https://name.sijisuru.com/Rank/fname/?keyword=%E5%8F%A3&type=2&pages=1), where 森口 is ranked 21st on the list. It might not have been easy to find even on that website, though, since you say in your comment: `I wasn't able to figure out the two 木's at the bottom` (So now I've reopened the question).
Additionally, I think you could probably have tried a handwritten kanji recognition tool, for example [this](https://scontent-itm1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/120306379_3347262685381591_4614760991474670614_n.jpg?_nc_cat=107&_nc_sid=730e14&_nc_ohc=Hr4F3w25TesAX8Z1rYp&_nc_ht=scontent-itm1-1.xx&oh=9131e7c32252177698a5cb73ab8aa57d&oe=5F966192) on [Google Translate](https://translate.google.co.jp/?hl=ja#view=home&op=translate&sl=ja&tl=ja).

Comment: `where 森口 is ranked 21st on the list` I did not have any idea of what the Kanji might be and it didn't look anything like 森 to me until you pointed it out. Handwritten Kanji recognition tool sound like a great idea! I will try using them next time. With that being said, closing it as off-topic because the question was asking for direct translation help without giving any reason does not really make sense to me. I would never have known the reason if I hadn't posted a question here.

Comment: You could have posted the links to handwritten kanji recognition tool (you did that and I am really thankful for that, but it was after the question was marked off topic and I asked a question here) and marked it off topic and I would have at least got to know the reason.